# Jqgrid Grouping - summary header?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Would it somehow be possible to display every column in the "Click to expand" row for grouping? For instance, in the Grouping demo [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), instead of showing simply the expand icon and the text "test", I want that row to contain table cells for every column.

For what I'm doing, I want that row to summarize/aggregate the data for each row in the group. So initially, that row will contain the summarized data when the grid is loaded, and the user can click to expand to view the details.

So basically, I want a summary header instead of a summary footer, and the expand icon should be on this header row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I got it to work. I'm letting JqGrid do all the work of aggregating the data and then, I simply take all children (table cells) of the footer row and place them inside the header row.

Note: If you have the summary footer rows turned on in the grouping view, you have to make sure that the footer row is present even though you're not using it (and even though nothing is in it). If you don't, and you try to expand the group, it'll end up expanding every group below it.

Comment: At what point are you pulling the cells out of the footer row and placing them in the header row? onGridComplete?  Can you show your code for this?  Hows the performance?